# d3js: Unable to set a value to .attr("font-size") properly, using a if else check function in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm working on a D3.js chart, and I'm trying to set a value if the chart is being rendered on mobile device or in desktop. I tried using an if else check funcion this way:

```js
.style("font-size", function(){
  if (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || $(window).width() < 550){
    return "40px"
  }
  else{
    return "10px"
  }
})
```

However that way wont work. If i remove all the `OR` and only check `window.innerWidth` in the condition, it does work. and my problem is already solved.

But My question is , why it doens't work having multiple `||` in the condition if, after all all the ones that are not valid should be disposed and if at least one of the is valid, it that one should be `true` and enter in the function properly?

any answer will be very appreciated :)

Comment: look at operator precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement's conditions are incorrect.
If you want to check each of them against a size you need to add the size to each condition.

```
 if (window.innerWidth < 550 || document.documentElement.clientWidth < 550 ||  
        document.body.clientWidth < 550 || $(window).width() < 550){
```